# Can't Find Theme Templates in WP File Editor in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I've recently come into the role of the marketing/tech guy at my company. What started as trying to move a form from the top of my page to the bottom quickly turned into combing through every file on the site that we have. We recently had a big company do our Website. It's great but they have their theme they use. They also do Google PPC for us with a landing page using Advanced Custom Fields. I've started running YouTube and hulu ads but needed my landing page for tracking metrics, so I just duplicated theirs and changed the form. the issue is, that they have the "getmore info" form first thing. and on mobile that lowers conversion rate. I've gone through ACF and made my own group and changed things around, but realized there was no way for me to make this ACF group page a page template. I checked in the theme folder in our file editor and there's no templates folder at all. does anyone know where they might be hiding this template in the theme files?

Already looked in theme file editor and no templates folder.

Comment: Since you can write any custom PHP code, you may want to try out plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/, or https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/, to check which file is 'running' the current page. It may even not be a page-template, it can be even just index.php or home.php.
I guess you can't post the folder structure for security reasons, so try this simple solution.